# Error when using Emoticons as Wordpress Post-Tags

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I´ve created a Wordpress-Post-Tag with a Emoji-Code: 
This works fine, even as slug in the Url. (Some Browsers convert the  to bytes.)

The problem ist now, that I can´t add this Tag from the "Choose from the most used tags" Tagcloud. The input is focused, but no Emoji occurs - it stays empty.

[WP Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5YFs.png)

My question: how can I fix that behaviour without touching wordpress core?
Or should I post a bug report at Wordpress?

Thanks for any advice!

(This is my first post, so be polite please  )

Comment: ok,can you please tell which plugin are you use for emoji?

Comment: As I understand,you want to tag emoji,right??

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Smilies

Comment: I´m not using any plugin. Wordpress does everything. The problem only occurs when adding a already used Emoji as Tag.

Comment: **already used** means??

Comment: You are use emoji for tag right.

Comment: Yes. And I can see it under the Link "Choose from the most used tags"

Comment: You have to ask for WordPress support.

Comment: I have created a bug report now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your database’s collation setting doesn’t support these types of characters.But as you say emoji is not available after select it once.

For This issue,You have to report in WordPress support.